# Porque no veo las imágenes en mi proyecto que subí a github?

Tags: github

Algunas si las veo, pero por el ejemplo la que está como background subida en index.css, que se llama futbolargentino.jpg, no la puedo ver. Esta en /assets/img/futbolargentino.jpg

En el local host si se puede ver

https://github.com/podolsky14/salondelafama

https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-wind-ij4rx?file=/src/index.css:433-464

Answer (score 1):

como andas? Podrias intentar en el componente importar la imagen y pasarla directo como `style` en el contenedor.

```
      import slide1 from "../assets/img/slide1.jpg";
      import slide2 from "../assets/img/slide2.jpg";
      import slide3 from "../assets/img/slide3.jpg";
      import "../index.css";

      // AQUI
      import futbol from "../assets/img/futbolargentino.JPG";

      export default function Home() {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="home" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${futbol})` }}>
              <h1 className="bienvenidos">
                Bienvenidos al Salón de la Fama del Fútbol Argentino
              </h1>

              <br />
            </div>
            <p className="d-flex m-3 ">
              {" "}
              El fútbol argentino es uno de los más laureados y reconocidos del mundo.
              Sus comienzos se remontan hacia finales del siglo XIX, aunque solo era
              jugado mayormente por británicos -que habian traido el deporte rey a el
              continente americano-. Las primeras figuras nativas comenzaron a surgir
              en los albores del siglo XX como los hermanos Brown y el mediocampista
              ofensivo Arnold Watson Hutton. En la década de los 10´s, Racing Club
              dominaria el campeonato local de la mano del futbolista Alberto Ohaco,
              quien fuera quizás la primera gran superestrella del fútbol argentino.
              En los 20´s el fútbol local seguiria creciendo a pasos agigantados con
              Boca Juniors, Huracán, San Lorenzo, Independiente y Racing. La Selección
              Argentina se estableceria definitivamente como una potencia mundial y el
              futbolista Manuel Seoane seria el más destacado de dicho periodo. En la
              década del 30 el futbol argentino se profesionaliza y en consecuencia su
              nivel mejora aún más con las gratas apariciones de Luis Monti, Raimundo
              Orsi y Antonio Sastre, entre otros grandes talentos. La Selección
              Argentina finaliza subcampeona del mundo en 1930. En la década
              siguiente, es una época de oro debido a gran generación de futbolistas
              como José Manuel Moreno, Adolfo Pedernera, Rinaldo Martino, Norberto
              Mendez y demás. Lamentablemente la Segunda Guerra Mundial impidió que
              las competiciones mundialistas se llevaran a cabo; sin embargo el
              seleccionado gana 4 Campeonatos Sudamericanos de forma arrolladora. Por
              aquel entonces se destacó River Plate y su famoso equipo apodado como
              "La Máquina". En los 50´s River Plate sigue dominando el ámbito local y
              el seleccionado argentino alterna buenas y malas: ganando los
              Campeonatos Sudamericanos de 1957 y 1959; pero quedando afuera
              rapidamente en la Copa Mundial de 1958. Asimismo, Alfredo Di Stéfano fue
              indiscutidamente el mejor futbolista de la década, haciendo historia con
              el Real Madrid. En la década del 60, Boca Juniors, Racing Club,
              Estudiantes e Independiente se erigen como los principales equipos. La
              Selección Argentina hace un digno torneo mundialista en 1966 de la mano
              de un recordado equipo. En los 70´s surgen grandes figuras como Daniel
              Passarella, Mario Kempes, Ricardo Bochini, Norberto Alonso y Ubaldo
              Fillol. A nivel clubes, Independiente se establece como el rey de
              América al ser el club más ganador de la competición; y tanto River
              Plate como Boca Juniors dominan la segunda parte de la década. A nivel
              Selección, el conjunto albiceleste obtiene su primer campeonato
              mundialista en 1978, lo cual fue celebrado con gran júbilo en todo el
              pais. En los 80´s el genio Diego Maradona pone el tela de juicio el
              reinado de Pelé como el rey del fútbol al llevar al Seleccionado
              Argentino a ganar la Copa Mundial de 1986 y al conducir al humilde
              Nápoli a ganar sendos títulos en Italia y Europa. En la década del 90,
              la Seleccion Nacional demuestra seguir estando en la elite ganando las
              Copas Américas de 1991 y 1993, de la mano de una gran generación de
              jugadores como Gabriel Batistuta, Fernando Redondo y Claudio Caniggia.
              En el ámbito local River Plate y Velez Sarfield serian los abanderados.
              En el siglo XXI, durante la primera década, Boca Juniors tiene su época
              dorada al ganar absolutamente todo a nivel local e internacional. Su
              figura, Juan Román Riquelme, seria junto a Juan Sebastian Veron y Javier
              Zanetti, el jugador más destacado. Por su parte la Selección Argentina
              sigue manteniendose entre las mejores del mundo, aunque sin ganar ningun
              trofeo. En el siguiente decenio hasta la actualidad, Lionel Messi se
              alzaria como la gran superestrella mundial de la era, llegando a la
              final de la Copa Mundial en 2014 y obteniendo la Copa América de 2021. A
              nivel clubes, Boca Juniors y River Plate serian los más distinguidos.
            </p>
            <br />
            <br />

            <div
              id="carouselExampleDark"
              className="carousel carousel-dark slide"
              data-bs-ride="carousel"
            >
              <div className="carousel-indicators">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark"
                  data-bs-slide-to="0"
                  className="active"
                  aria-current="true"
                  aria-label="Slide 1"
                ></button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark"
                  data-bs-slide-to="1"
                  aria-label="Slide 2"
                ></button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark"
                  data-bs-slide-to="2"
                  aria-label="Slide 3"
                ></button>
              </div>
              <div className="carousel-inner">
                <div className="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="3000">
                  <img src={slide1} className="d-block w-100" alt="slide1" />
                  <div className="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Diego Armando Maradona</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
                  <img src={slide2} className="d-block w-100" alt="slide2" />
                  <div className="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Lionel Messi</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="3000">
                  <img src={slide3} className="d-block w-100" alt="slide3" />
                  <div className="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Alfredo Di Stéfano</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button
                className="carousel-control-prev"
                type="button"
                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark"
                data-bs-slide="prev"
              >
                <span
                  className="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
              <button
                className="carousel-control-next"
                type="button"
                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark"
                data-bs-slide="next"
              >
                <span
                  className="carousel-control-next-icon"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
```

Comment: Me funcionó. Muchas gracias.

Comment: buenisimo! :D sigue asi!! no recuerdes evaluar la respuesta!